# Как отключить подсказку в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, помогите выключить эту подсказку. На фото все показано.

Comment: Это называется IntelliCode. Что мешает просто не жать Tab, когда не требуется? Я когда пишу код, мне часто эти подсказки экономят время.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70097398/12888024

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!